# Using the winrm communicator on a Linux host

Tags: linux, vagrant, vagrantfile, winrm

I'm setting up a Windows 2008 Server machine and all morning I was on a Windows host so winrm didn't cause any problems until now. I switched over to Linux thought and whenever I set my communicator to winrm, vagrant isn't able to communicate with my guest machine anymore and I don't want (read: can't, for a variety of reasons) to install Cygwin on it.

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "box/win-server-2008"
  config.vm.communicator = "winrm"
end
```

And this is the error I get:

```
/home/guyllaume/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-windows-1.6.0/lib/vagrant-windows/windows_machine.rb:62:in `winrmshell': undefined method `winrmshell' for #<VagrantPlugins::CommunicatorWinRM::Communicator:0x00000001f65ad0> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/guyllaume/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-windows-1.6.0/lib/vagrant-windows/guest/cap/configure_networks.rb:19:in `configure_networks'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:43:in `capability'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:132:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:15:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:84:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:160:in `handle'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:42:in `block in call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:41:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:50:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:36:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:196:in `action_raw'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:173:in `block in action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:474:in `lock'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:161:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.6.5/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/logging-1.8.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `call'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/logging-1.8.2/lib/logging/diagnostic_context.rb:323:in `block in create_with_logging_context'
```

I saw a video from the Vagrant guys where they used winrm with no problem on a Mac (right [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-windows.html)) and I would hope it also works on Linux, but I can't seem to get it to work.

If any one can help me see my error I'd greatly appreciate. So far Vagrant has been quite a challenge to learn. Fun, but really challenging.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, maybe it wasn't clear or I wasn't attentive enough, but winrm is a Ruby gem, not a Linux package.

`gem install -r winrm` will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

After install `gem install winrm`, we will get a complain about :

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- winrm-elevated (LoadError)
```

so we should install both `winrm` and `winrm-elevated`

```
gem install winrm
gem install winrm-elevated
```